# seaborn.catplot() hue is not working properly

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, catplot

I am trying to replace a `seaborn.facetgrid` with a `seaborn.catplot`. But the `seaborn.catplot` does not properly label the hue in the `Embarked = C` facet.

dataset: titanic

---

```py
e = sns.FacetGrid(data= train_df, col='Embarked')
e.map_dataframe(sns.pointplot, 'Pclass', 'Survived', hue='Sex', palette='deep')
e.add_legend()
```

[image: at Embarked C male is properly presented as hue]

**Embarked C**: male is properly presented as hue

---

But my `seaborn.catplot` shows:

```
sns.catplot(x='Pclass', y= 'Survived', hue='Sex', data=train_df, kind='point',  col='Embarked')
```

[image: in Emabarked= C male is not properly hued]

**Embarked C**:
**male** is not properly presented as hue

Comment: Your first plot is wrong.  You can force a consistent order on the hue values, either by providing `hue_order=['male','female']` or by making that column categorical (`train_df['Sex'] = pd.Categorical(train_df['Sex'])`)

Answer (score 0):

JohanC already teased the answer in his comment. I will just explicate and complete.

Here is what the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) of `seaborn.catplot` says about ordering:

> As in the case with the underlying plot functions, if variables have a *categorical* data type, the levels of the categorical variables, and their order will be inferred from the objects. Otherwise you may have to use alter the dataframe sorting or use the function parameters (`orient`, `order`, `hue_order`, etc.) to set up the plot correctly.

This means you could e.g. use the `hue_order` parameter to make sure the plot is ordered like you want it to:

> **order, hue_order: lists of strings, optional**
> Order to plot the categorical levels in, otherwise the levels are inferred from the data objects.

Here how to use it in your case:

```py
sns.catplot(x='Pclass', y='Survived', hue='Sex', hue_order=['male', 'female'], data=train_df, kind='point', col='Embarked')
```

Alternatively, as described in the documentation and pointed out by JohanC, you can convert the type of the column `train_df['Sex']` to be categorical. Then the order will be inferred by `seaborn`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  JohanC. Yes my FacetGrid plot was wrong. I checked it manually.

```
train_df[(train_df['Embarked']=='C') & (train_df['Survived']==1)].groupby('Sex').count()['Survived']
```

output:

```
Sex
    female    64
    male      29
```

Female is larger than male.
In `FacetGrid` `hue_order` should be specified otherwise it may give wrong result.